# Autohotkey - control volume and exit with mouse on youtube, facebook while in fullscreen

Tags: autohotkey

I want to control volume with mouse and exit from fullscreen with mouse middle click on youtube, facebook only while flash player is in fullscreen on chrome or firefox. My screen resolution is 1920x1080, so when window is maximized window info tool shows width: 1936, when fullscreen width: 1920 so idea is to check window width:

```
~WheelUp::
WinGetActiveStats, Title, Width, Height, X, Y
if (Width = 1920) and WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") or WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass") {
 SendInput {Volume_Up 5}
}
return

~WheelDown::
WinGetActiveStats, Title, Width, Height, X, Y
if (Width = 1920) and WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") or WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass") {
 SendInput {Volume_Down 5}
}
return

~MButton::
WinGetActiveStats, Title, Width, Height, X, Y
if (Width = 1920) and WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") or WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass") {
 SendInput {Escape}
}
return
```

It works, but how I can add title part (youtube, facebook) to check? Also mouse middle click not only sending escape (same with F11), but also resize window. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Title contains the word YouTube or Facebook.

```
~WheelUp::
WinGetClass, Class, A
WinGetActiveStats, Title, Width, Height, X, Y
if (InStr(Title,"YouTube") or InStr(Title,"Facebook")) 
and (Width = 1920) 
and (Class = "ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1" or Class = "ahk_class MozillaWindowClass") {
    SendInput {Volume_Up 5}
}
return
```

Comment: Since you're getting the active window's stats, this condition is redundant `and (WinActive("ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1") or WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass"))`.